# How do I permanently unmute my microphone?

Tags: audio, microphone, logitech-headset, noise-cancelling

I am using Logitech H370 USB Headset with Noise-Cancelling Microphone on my laptop. However, the noise-cancelling feature only works when I manually turn on the microphone in Playback -> Speakers -> Levels -> Microphone. (See attached photo.)

[image: Click on this link to view the picture.]

How do I permanently unmute my microphone? I already searched online but didn't find anyone who has the same problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did Logitech customer support say when you contacted them?

Comment: I am still waiting for their reply. I ordered the headset online and just received it today.